# Alt-F4 sometimes stucks and sometimes closes many windows at once

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have a Dell XPS 15 - 9560 running Ubuntu 16.04 and I am experiencing the following problem:

When I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> to close a window, sometimes it just won't close or take some time to respond. Then again, some other times it would close 3-4 windows altogether (firstly the first active, then the second which becomes active and so on..).

Any ideas on what should be the cause of the problem? I don't think its' a hardware issue, because as I can recall, I didn't have much trouble with it under Windows.

Comment: No, I own a laptop. So I guess the connection is stable (since in windows it was working well). Or was this a question about drivers?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, exact same laptop. Anyone know how to fix it yet?